# Graph API requesting friends pagination doesn't work in Graph Explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use v2.0 of the Facebook API to do the simplest thing - return a list of friends.

But all I get is a random set of about 5 friends, and pagination returns nothing.

```
/v2.0/[fb_user_id]/friends/
```

I'm totally flummoxed. I've done this a million times. I've tried in the Graph Explorer and in my code. I've tried with every permission. The v2.0 API just seems totally broken.

Can anyone shed light on this? Thanks!

Comment: Is it really a “random” set of five different friends each time – or are they the _same_ five friends every time? If the latter, then you neglected to keep yourself informed about what has changed with API 2.0 regarding access to a user’s friends …

Comment: You are sure right, thanks for the tip. "Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app."